# Walmart.com Price Scraping with Python and bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to scrape price from a page on Walmart but getting an error.  Below is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.walmart.com/ip/Wilson-The-Duke-Official-NFL-Game-Football/5192758"
page = requests.get(URL,headers={"User-Agent":"Defined"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
price = soup.find(id="price-group").get_text()
print(price)
```

I get the following output on the command line:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "walmart.py", line 7, in 
>       price = soup.find(id="price-group").get_text()
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

I am seeing a similar error for Nordstorm and Sears.

Can someone please help?

Comment: "price-group' sounds more like  a class name than an ID. I've never used beautiful soup, but petty sure that's what the code looks for. Are you sure the page contains that id?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 is right, if you go to the page and inspect the price, "price-group" is the class name, not the ID.

Comment: Related older question: [Walmart Price Scraping with Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25189056/walmart-price-scraping-with-python-3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have looked at the given URL and the price-group seems to be the class name rather than the ID. So you need:

```
price = soup.find(class_="price-group").get_text()
```

Comment: Didn't work.  I got the Syntax error.   File "walmart.py", line 7
    price = soup.find(class="price-group").get_text()
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @user9465677 can you try `class_ = "price-group"`  class is a reserved keyword. that's why u got the error.